# Explain why .bash_logout won't run commands?

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, .bash-profile

So I've been wondering how to run these two lines of code everytime I close an open instance of Terminal:

```
history -c
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
```

I `export HISTFILE=5` on startup, but still want to flush that out when I'm done.

I've tried [looking around a bit](https://superuser.com/questions/299836/attaching-some-code-to-session-start-and-end-in-linux) in a [couple of places](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/tag/bash_logout/), and [haven't had much luck](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/advanced/node125.html).

I run Linux Mint, and would also note here that I ran into a similar issue with `.bash_profile`; eventually, I discovered I needed to place all start up code in `.bashrc`, so maybe that has something to do with it. Here's my `.bash_logout` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/.bash_logout: executed by bash(1) when login shell exits.

#this does nothing on exit...
echo 'logout'; sleep 2s

# when leaving the console clear the screen to increase privacy

if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    history -c
    cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

I've tried re-arranging this script many ways, I'm not sure if I don't understand how bash works, and if any of this is running in the first place. Does the fact that I run `Xserver` make bash consider Terminal [something that isn't a log-out on exit?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash_logout-does-not-get-executed-104906/)

It does say that I am **not** logged in, which would make sense:

```
$> shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

Comment: As a general comment, if you’re testing whether or not a shell config script is getting run, I recommend you put the `echo` command at the start, before it does anything else that could interfere with the `echo` getting run. An error could cause the script to exit before it gets to the end.

Comment: I was assuming from the way you phrased this, and the fact that you’re checking for SHLVL=1, that you already verified that it’s a login shell. Is it? What does `shopt login_shell` say?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you’ve verified that it’s a login shell (`shopt login_shell`):

~/.bash_logout is only run if it  you explicitly exit the shell with `exit` or `logout`, or by typing Control-D to enter an end-of-file at the command prompt. If you close the terminal emulator, processes are sent SIGHUP, and bash doesn’t run ~/.bash_logout in that case.

If you want to perform work any time bash exits (and whether it’s a login shell or not), use `trap foo EXIT`. The most convenient way to do this is to put your code in a shell function, e.g.,:

```
print_goodbye () { echo Goodbye; }
trap print_goodbye EXIT
```

Comment: I feel like a wasted a perfectly good problem on my bad question. I'll ask again if I get past your *first sentence* and still have trouble. Sheesh.

Answer (score 7):

`~/.bash_logout` is only run by a *login* shell (such as the one you get on tty sessions, or with `bash -l`). It is ignored by non-login shells, which most terminals run.

See the manual page of bash(1), under "INVOCATION", for further detail.

---

If you do not want to keep persistent history, just unset `HISTFILE`, or set `HISTFILE=/dev/null`. This will automatically discard history on exit, while still allowing it to be kept for the current shell (`HISTSIZE=100`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should be able to achieve same result (retaining history only for current session without saving it to disk) using following **command**:

```
>$HISTFILE;export HISTFILE=;echo "export HISTFILE=" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Run that command for each user for which you want to:
empty bash history file; unset bash history file

**Result**: It apparently only remember history within active session (in memory accessible to particular user), view current session history using "history" command, NOT saving it to bash_history or any other file on disk.

After i have killed terminal application with active session and login again, history was gone from file and history command output.