# Is it possible to modify .bash_logout?

Tags: bash, unix, centos-5

I am trying to modify .bash_logout to append the shell history to a txt file. I am also trying to figure to make some restrictions on that file.
I have tried a bunch of commands while searching about it on google but nothing seems to be working.
Is there any possible way to do it?

Here are some commands that I tried.

```
# avoid duplicates..
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  
# append history entries..
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, save and reload history
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Also tried:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Yes, there is a possible way to do it, but could you please add what you've tried already? "A bunch of commands" isn't very specific. Also see: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's actually the commands which I though might help me but did almost nothing(or that's what I think). Would you like to see them anyway?

Comment: As stated in the link I just posted: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Understood. I will edit my question in a minute.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/410525/explain-why-bash-logout-wont-run-commands

Comment: `.bash_logout` is only run if `shopt login_shell` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use traps to do this.

for example, put something like this in your .bash_profile:

```
function save_history
{
    ~/.bash_history >> ~/mybackup_history.txt
}
trap save_history EXIT
```

### Links to Additional Resources On Traps

[Some background on `trap` statements](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Trap_statement)

[A blog post with plenty of `trap` examples](http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/)

[A chapter on traps from a Bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

[A Unix & Linux Stack exchange question about traps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/trap-err-and-echoing-the-error-line)