# .bash_logout not executing on MX Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

As stated in title no joy from `.bash_logout` when I exit the terminal (same result when logging in on a virtual i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

I've tried everything listed here: [Explain why .bash_logout won't run commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/410525/explain-why-bash-logout-wont-run-commands)

So what am I doing wrong or what is misconfigured or what is my wrong assumption?

In "Terminal Preferences" I've enabled "Run command as login shell" and this is my `.bash_logout`:

```bash
#echo Goodbye to verify .bash_logout ran

print_goodbye () { echo Goodbye; }

trap print_goodbye EXIT
```

`echo $BASH_VERSION` prints `5.1.4(1)-release`.

Comment: Perhaps you are not actually running bash!

Comment: The output of 
$ echo $0 -bash indicates that I am.

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: Check: `shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'`

Comment: (1) "when I exit the terminal" – Where exactly do you expect to see `Goodbye` since you *exit* the terminal? In the terminal that no longer exists? (2) "same result when logging in on a virtual" – It's quite common the virtual console gets cleared immediately after a user logs out. What you see is similar to `echo Goodbye; clear`. // Instead of `echo Goodbye;` try `echo Goodbye; sleep 2;`. (3) [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/410534/432690) states `.bash_logout` is not run in some circumstances. You used the workaround, but implemented it inside `.bash_logout`. Do you see the flaw?